# How to rename commits with wrong author in git

Tags: git, github

I've been working for a few months in a github project y and a bunch of the commits i've made are not assigned to me because of "wrong author info".

Is there a way to cycle through this commits or update the author to all of them at once? They most be 100 or so.

Thanks

UPDATE:
 Got this error trying to run the script on git bash:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRn5.png)

And this one on windows cmd: [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZLG4.png)
Help anyone? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to rewrite history in GIT.

Comment: @SiKing You believe wrong. Granted, it's usually strongly dis-recommended, but it is very definitely possible, and not even all that difficult.

Comment: @twalberg Hmmm, George Orwell would be proud. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use filter-branch

```bash
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name>" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name>";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email>";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD `
```

If you are the **ONLY** user who committed to this repository you can simply update all references without checking the old content

```bash
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Newname"
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="newemail"
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Newname"
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="newemail"
  ' HEAD
```

Comment: I think the first one is exactly what i need what i can't run it!

Answer (score 3):

You can amend commit editing author:

```
git commit --amend --author="John Doe <someone@example.com>"
```

Or use interactive rebase to edit multiple commits. Do **git rebase -i HEAD~5**, then mark all required commits for editing and recommit them with correct author field as in single commit example above.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you can change email addresses in multiple commits in a batch with `filter-branch` as well. You need to be careful to change only the email addresses that are yours, so you use `--commit-filter`:

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "schacon@localhost" ];
        then
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Scott Chacon";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="schacon@example.com";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

This goes through and rewrites every commit to have your new address. Because commits contain the SHA-1 values of their parents, this command changes every commit SHA-1 in your history, not just those that have the matching email address.

Reference : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: This is it but using "invalid-email-address" in the IF statment right?